# List of sources could not be read

Tags: package-management, playonlinux

i am getting this error when i try to run the update list command in order to correct the red minus sign on the top bar:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

E: Type' !DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Solution please??

Answer (score 2):

The file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` contains HTML instead of a proper source list entry. Delete it:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
```